# How to constant 0 in the range when the number is not inputed

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

In cell `A1` I have number entered as 10. If I delete the number 10 from the cell `A1` I want 0 to be constant in the cell `A1` automatically instead of manual entry of 0?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please **[edit]** your question to include what you've tried so far.

Comment: There is a difference between delete and subtract.  If you subtract, you will get a remainder, which could be zero.  If you delete, no contents will remain.  If you want to delete and then have a zero, you would need to create the zero as a replacement entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for Macros, though you didn't tag it.

Number Formatting can not be used here as the cell is null.

Put the below code into your macros, for some reason I had to put this into the code on "Sheet1" - when I tried to create a separate Module (which we would usually do) or put it in "ThisWorkbook" it didn't pick it up.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rMonitor As Range, cell As Range

    ' Change this Range to match what you want to monitor (eg, just A1:A20)
    Set rMonitor = Range("A1:G20")

    For Each cell In Target
        If Not Intersect(cell, rMonitor) Is Nothing Then
            If cell = "" Then
                cell = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    Set rMonitor = Nothing
        Set rTarget = Nothing
End Sub
```